# Verification of two proofs

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Hi I have to do two proof questions for my homework and I'm not sure whether their good enough. The question is:

"Let $f : [a, b] → R$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(a, b)$.

(a) We assume that $f(a) < f(p)$ and $f(p) > f(b)$ for some $p ∈ (a,b)$. Show that there exists $d ∈ (a,b)$ such that $f′(d) = 0$.

(b) Show that, if $f′(x) = 1$ for all $x ∈ (a,b)$, then there exists a constant $C ∈ R$ such that $f (x) = x + C$ for all $x ∈ (a, b)$."

What I've done so far:

For (a) where IVT = intermediate value theorem and theorem 12.2 states that. "If $f$ has a local minimum or local maximum at $c ∈ (a, b)$ and if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f′(c) = 0$.":

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCkbJ.jpg)

For (b)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwfBK.jpg)

Comment: both look good.

Comment: Which is the good solution for $(a)$? The first part or the second one? In there an IGNORE in front of the first part? For $(b)$ you should write $\exists c\in (a,x): f(x)-f(a)=f'(c)(x-a).$

Comment: Yeah sorry there's an ignore in the first part of a

Comment: But that was the correct solution. You can't say that $p$ is a maximum.

Comment: your setup in a) as you transcribed it does not mach what is in the picture in the link.  As it shows here, now the premise is not true. (but it is correct on the linked photo.)

Comment: Oh right ok thanks I'll cross out the second proof for part (a)

Comment: What do you mean my setup sorry?